# Multithreading with Singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, singleton

I created a `PrintQueue` class which does printing related job. I made it singleton, as one network printer is shared by many users, so one instance should be created.

Here is my code:

```
abstract class Document {
    protected String name;
    protected String type;
    Document(){}
    Document(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String name(){
        return this.name;
    }
    abstract public String type();      
}

class TextDocument extends Document {
    TextDocument(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    public String type() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "text";
    }       
}

class PdfDocument extends Document {
    PdfDocument(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    @Override
    public String type() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "PDF";
    }   
}

class Node {
    public Document document;
    public Node next;
    Node(Document d){
        document = d;
    }    
}

class PrintQueue {
    public Node root;
    Node cur;
    private static PrintQueue instance;
    private PrintQueue(){}
    public static synchronized PrintQueue getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new PrintQueue();
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public  void push(Document d){
        if(root == null){
            root = new Node(d);
            root.next =null;
        }else{
             cur = root;
             while(cur.next!= null){
                 cur=cur.next;
             }
             Node newNode = new Node(d);
             cur.next = newNode;
             newNode.next = null;
         }

     }
     public Document pop(){
         if(root == null){
             System.out.println("Queue is empty");
             return null;
         }else{
             Node temp = root;
             root=root.next;
             System.out.println(temp.document.name()+"   "+temp.document.type()+" popped out");
             return temp.document;
         }
     }
     public void displayContent(){
         if(root == null){
             System.out.println("no pending task");
         }else{
             cur = root;
             while(cur!=null){
                System.out.println(cur.document.name()+"    "+cur.document.type()); 
                cur = cur.next;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    } 
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Document a= new PdfDocument("loan agreement");
        Document b= new TextDocument("Air Ticket");
        Document c= new PdfDocument("movie ticket");
        Document d= new TextDocument("bike riding");
        PrintQueue p = PrintQueue.getInstance();
        PrintQueue q = PrintQueue.getInstance();
        p.push(a);
        p.push(b);
        q.push(c);
        q.push(d);
        p.displayContent();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        p.pop();
        q.pop();
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------");
        p.displayContent();
    }    
}
```

I want to implement multithreading in my code where the `push()` method should be synchronized. Otherwise, if a document is sent by multiple users to the printer, it will not be saved in the print queue as expected.

I am new to multithreading, so I was thinking that I should extend `Thread` class to my `printQueue`, and in the `run()` method, I will call `push()`. However, I am unable to send a parameter to `push()` in that way and as my `printQueue` is singleton. I can't  initialize `document` to be passed to `push()` in the constructor of `printQueue`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand

- you are dealing with consumer and producer problem, which is suitable to use [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (example updated from doc) to keep the thread safety:

  ```
  class DocProducer implements Runnable {
      private final BlockingQueue queue;
      Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
      public void run() {
          try {
              while (true) { queue.put(produce()); }
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
      }
      Document produce() { ... }
  }

  class DocConsumer implements Runnable {
      private final BlockingQueue queue;
      Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
      public void run() {
          try {
              while (true) { consume(queue.take()); }
          } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
      }
      void consume(Document x) { ... }
  }

  class Setup {
      void main() {
          // or use your own thread-safe queue implementation,
          // which is harder to be right, though
          BlockingQueue printQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue();

          DocProducer p = new DocProducer(printQueue);
          DocConsumer c1 = new DocConsumer(printQueue);
          DocConsumer c2 = new DocConsumer(printQueue);
          new Thread(p).start();
          new Thread(c1).start();
          new Thread(c2).start();
      }
  }
  ```
- use runnalbe rather than extend thread, or better use `ExecutorService`
- you want your consumer and producer to be multithreaded, which should have multi threads, but not your `PrintQueue`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you want to avoid calling `push()` method of your `PrintQueue` by multiple threads at the same time, then just make that method `synchronized` -

```
     public synchronized void push(Document d){
         if(root == null){
             root = new Node(d);
             root.next =null;
         }else{
             cur = root;
             while(cur.next!= null){
                 cur=cur.next;
             }
             Node newNode = new Node(d);
             cur.next = newNode;
             newNode.next = null;
         }

     }
```

By making this method `synchronized`, you are ensuring that only one thread can enter inside this method at one time so will make this method `thread-safe`